# Htaccess redirect — both HTTP and HTTPS of particular domain to another domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I manage redirect of particular domain to another domain. And I need to redirect both HTTP and HTTPS requests.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example2.com [L,R=301,NC]
```

This code works only with HTTP.

I tried something like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
```

That obviously doesn't work!
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: Does certificate needed to https redirect could work?

Comment: _"Does certificate needed to https redirect could work?"_ - if you want to be able to redirect me, when I enter `https://example.com` or `https://www.example.com` into my browser - then yes, you need a valid certificate for those first of all, otherwise my browser will refuse to connect to those domains in the first place. And if it doesn't - then you can't redirect me elsewhere _from_ there either.